# How to filter output with Where-Object?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some info about applications cert on Windows 2019 (name and expiration date):

```
Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust | ?{$_.EncryptionCertificate} `
| Select-Object name,
@{n="CertificateExpiration";e={($_ | Select-Object EncryptionCertificate -ExpandProperty EncryptionCertificate).notafter}} | Sort-Object CertificateExpiration
```

Output:

[image: Script output 1]

But what if I want to get only those certs, which expire in near future (30 days for example)?
Tried to filter like this, but with no success:

```
Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust | ?{$_.EncryptionCertificate} `
| Select-Object name,
@{n="CertificateExpiration";e={($_ | Select-Object EncryptionCertificate -ExpandProperty EncryptionCertificate).notafter}} | Sort-Object CertificateExpiration `
| Where-Object ($_.CertificateExpiration - (Get-Date)).Days -le '30'
```

(output is same)

Comment: You do the filtering on the left, and the selecting on the right. First filter for the expired certs, then create your custom table. `Where-Object -Property EncryptionCertificate -LE (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) `

Comment: Pipe symbols can be the last symbol without need to backtick-brake. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `[DateTime] minus [DateTime]` gives you `[TimeSpan]` object which is representation of period. When converting to numerical `[Int]`, it uses `ticks` which is 0.0001s. To operate with some time units like Days, you should use `.TotalDays`
2. Converting to string `-le '30'` can be dangerous because of type conversion. Use numbers, not strings: `-le 30`.
3. `[DateTime]::Today` and `[DateTime]::Now` instead of what you're doing with `Get-Date` maybe better ;)

---

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
  Where-Object {$_.HasPrivateKey -eq $true} |
  Where-Object {($_.NotAfter - [DateTime]::Today).TotalDays -gt 30}
```

---

Instead of computing difference, I'd recommend to make "$warningDate" variable:

```
$warningDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(30)
$warnedCerts = @(Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' | 
   Where-Object {$_.NotAfter -le $warningDate})  # Use @() to force array if you're not sure on number of elements returned)
```